# How do I get the tensorflow model to persist load?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Now I want to write 2 functions:

- 1 for loading model that I already trained,
- 2nd is using the the model to classify.

But the two function all need same session, so I make the session as a parameter, so as to seed it to the next function. But I received an error.

Here is my code. The first method is for loading the model, the second one is for using the model to predict something, but I have a few problems while init the session

```
def callmodel():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        #saver = tf.train.Saver()
        model_path = 'E:/MyProject/MachineLearning/callTFModel/model/'
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
        sess = tf.Session()
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path + '.meta')
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            print("load model successful!")
            return sess
        else:
            print("failed to load model!")


def test_one_image(sess,test_dir):
    global p, logits
    image = Image.open(test_dir)
    image = image.resize([32, 32])
    image_array = np.array(image)
    image = tf.cast(image_array, tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [1, 32, 32, 3])  # 调整image的形状
    p = mmodel(image, 1)
    logits = tf.nn.softmax(p)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[32, 32, 3])
    prediction = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x: image_array})
    max_index = np.argmax(prediction)
    if max_index == 0:
        print('probability of good： %.6f' % prediction[:, 0])
    else:
        print('probability of Lack of glue： %.6f' % prediction[:, 1])



#######//test
sess=callmodel
path="c:/test/1001.jpg"
test_one_image(sess,path)

it occurs error:

 File "E:/MyProject/python/C+pythonModel/test.py", line 175, in <module>
    test_one_image(sess,path)
  File "E:/MyProject/python/C+pythonModel/test.py", line 164, in test_one_image
    prediction = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x: image_array})
  File "D:\study\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\study\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1071, in _run
    + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with using the session as parameter, it's with how you recover the input and output nodes of your graph: when you write

```
p = mmodel(image, 1)
logits = tf.nn.softmax(p)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[32, 32, 3])
```

you are not recovering the corresponding nodes in the session graph, but creating new ones. You should instead use:

```
x= sess.graph().get_tensor_by_name("your_x_placeholder_name")
logits= sess.graph().get_tensor_by_name("your_logits_placeholder_name")
```

and then `prediction = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x: image_array})`

Additionnally, you probably need to check if you have not made any mistake between `image` and `image_array` (right now you're reshaping `image`, not the array, which is useless if you feed with `image_array`...)